# Optimize with joins, order, distinct on current active records / sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I am using ruby on rails 4 and postgres currently, and making distinct and sorting as in the code below.

I just have a feeling is not right and not optimized because it seems to be doing all this with an array.

How could I combine this all into one activerecords query ?

```
ads1 = Advertisement.where(property_id: nil)
                    .where(target_address_city: [property.address_city, ""], 
                           target_address_state: [property.address_state, ""], 
                           target_address_country_id: property.address_country_id)              
# return advertisement belongs to the property
ads2 = management.property.advertisements
#combine both results
combine_ads = ads1 + ads2
#remove ads duplicate
uniq_ads = combine_ads.uniq { |ads| ads.id}
# sort by created_at desc
uniq_ads = uniq_ads.sort_by { |ads| -ads[:id]}
# do pagination
final_ads = uniq_ads.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:page_limit])
```

Comment: Did you try to craft a raw SQL request ? I know many would say ActiveRecord as been created to avoid this, but sometimes a raw request offer better performance.

Comment: i think i fixed it with concat(), but do advise if that is correct

Comment: Please, update your initial post with your progress to help us understand.